# Is swift let equivalent to objective-c const?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is this in Swift:

`let someString:String = "blah"`

Effectively equivalent to this in Objective-C:

`NSString * const someString = @"blah";`

I've been assuming that the use of the **const** keyword in this way in Objective-C has been making it effectively equivalent to let in Swift, under the hood, but it would be nice to hear that confirmed.  It's rare that anyone uses const in this way when defining local variables in Objective-C, but it seems equivalent to let.  Given the benefits of let, ensuring no mutation of the pointer can occur later, I'm wondering if my existing Objective-C projects wouldn't benefit by using this convention all the time.  My question is not about the difference between Swift String and NSString.

Comment: They are similar, not equivalent. The Objective-C (and C) case is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Provided** you place the `const` *after* the type, as in:

```
NSString * const someString = @"blah"; // your example

struct { int x; int y; } const someStruct = { 42, 24 }; // const value type
```

then the semantics of `const` in (Objective-)C and `let` in Swift are similar. For value types both prevent the modification of the value. For reference types both prevent the modification of the reference itself and allow modification of the referenced object.

If you place the `const` elsewhere in the declaration then you enter the labyrinth of C pointers to constants, constant pointers, constant pointers to constants, and longer chains of (non-)constant combinations. Not everyone who enters this labyrinth returns... or at least not with their sanity intact. You have been warned! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can define let and var in Objective-C. Simply save the header (swifty.h) and use it (#import "swifty.h" where you need or add to Prefix Header file pch) :

```
#ifndef let
#define let __auto_type const 
#endif

#ifndef var
#define var __auto_type 
#endif
```

Comment: :) This seems like an awesome idea but I haven't seen it used in any code yet.

Comment: @scrrr OneSignal use it in their code: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK