# Differences Objective-C const and let Swift in terms of run and compile time

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am trying to figure out difference between Objective-C and Swift constant. I just read a tutorial document

```
//Objective-C
const int number = 0;
//Swift
let number = 0
```

> "A const is a variable initialized at compile time with a value or an expression that must be resolved at compilation time.
> An immutable created with let is a constant determined at runtime. You can initialize it with a static or a dynamic expression. This allows a declaration such as:

```
let higherNumber = number + 5
```

> Note that you can only assign its value once."

Can someone explain these phrases and deep little dive into to explain why let constant determined at runtime ? I was thinking let is constant and never change.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari can you explain with code what the difference is ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is swift let equivalent to objective-c const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067553/is-swift-let-equivalent-to-objective-c-const)

Comment: @Sandeep thanks but there is no answer about compile and runtime difference

Comment: I dont think there exists a difference, they are very similar, once the value is assigned they dont let you change the value (for value types) and wont change let you change the reference (for reference type) but both wont stop you from changing the value of property of reference type itself, also the statement that let allows dynamic/static expression seems like point author is trying to make is Objective-C const does not, but thats not true, You can assign static or dynamic expression to Objective-C const as well, their behavior seems pretty similar to each other.

Comment: Just supporting my comment about static/dynamic expression allocation in swift and objective-c, this is perfectly valid in swift `let value = Int.random(in: 0..<6) % 2 == 0 ? "Sandeep" : "Bhandari"` and so is `int r = arc4random_uniform(74);` `NSString *const someOtherValue = (r % 2 == 0) ? @"abcd" : @"efgh"; ` in objective-C, not sure what point author of the tutorial you are pointing trying to make with that statement

Comment: Is this a swift or objective-c focused question? Multi-language questions should be avoided.

Comment: @drainopener: You can probably update the question with link to tutorial you mentioned, is it an official apple doc you are referring to? Interesting question though hence +1. Keep the link posted just wanna know whats the intention of author

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you can focus one and answer with one. It is okay for me.

Comment: @Sandeep This is the the raywenderlich interview question

Comment: `const int higherNumber = number + 5;` is allowed in Objective-C. Whether an expression is resolved at compile time or at runtime is an implementation detail and can be different in other (versions of) compilers or with other build settings. Post a link to the tutorial please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let means once assigned the value can’t be changed. The compiler will enforce that. An expression like “let now=Date()” can’t be determined at compile time but at compile time you can disallow reassigning to “now”.. “let pi = 3.141” can be determined at compile time, enabling optimisations and that is like C’s const

Note for reference types (classes) let means the assigned object will continue to be the same object, it doesn’t mean the object itself can’t or doesn’t change.

Comment: Thank you but I could not fully understand your answer. Also i don't know C.

Comment: Is Swift `let now=Date()` the same as Objective-C `const NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];`?

Comment: No let with reference type object is like a constant pointer not a pointer to a constant. That’s spelled with the const after the type